# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'union'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

When I use the code below, I get an attribute error.

My code:

```
df_1.loc[df_2.year <= 5, 'old']\
        = (df_1.loc[df_2.year<= 5, 'old'].apply(lambda x:x.union({'old 
          product, '})))
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'union'
```

I have gone through many questions on Attribute Errors. However, I still do not understand why I am getting this error.

df1:
|     | year |
| ----| ---- |
| 0   | 5    |
| 1   | 0    |
| 2   | 1    |
| 3   | 9    |
| 4   | 2    |
| 5   | 0    |

df2:
|     | brand|
| ----| ---- |
| 0   | Nty  |
| 1   | ABB  |
| 2   | KIY  |
| 3   | HYT  |
| 4   | TTT  |
| 5   | 0TY  |

Comment: could you expand on what you are trying to achieve here? the `union` method works with sets, not strings.

Comment: The error tells you the problem, `str` objects don't have a `.union` attribute. If you provide a [mcve] for your issue we might be able to undertsnad your task better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `string` objects do not have a `union` function. You can use `+` instead-

```
df_1.loc[df_2.year <= 5, 'old'] = (df_1.loc[df_2.year<= 5, 'old'].apply(lambda x: x + 'old product, ' if isinstance(x, str) else x.union({'old product, '})))
```

Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp) for more examples.

Comment: It gives me error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'str'

Comment: It seems that the column contains both str and set values, please see my updated answer.